# How can I export a GridView.DataSource to a datatable or dataset?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How can I export `GridView.DataSource` to datatable or dataset?

Comment: what is the type of the object pointed to by GridView.DataSource?

Comment: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=474895

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should convert first `DataSource` in `BindingSource`, look example

```
BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)dgrid.DataSource; // Se convierte el DataSource 
DataTable tCxC = (DataTable) bs.DataSource;
```

With the data of `tCxC` you can do anything.

Answer (score 50):

Assuming your DataSource is of type DataTable, you can just do this:

```
myGridView.DataSource as DataTable
```

Comment: this is the best answer for this question, thank you

Comment: I set the `datagridview.DataSource = dataTable` but when I want to read that from `DataSource` by this ways , throw invalid cast exception by msg: `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'.`

Answer (score 19):

Personally I would go with:

```
DataTable tbl = Gridview1.DataSource as DataTable;
```

This would allow you to test for null as this results in either DataTable object or null.  Casting it as a DataTable using (DataTable)Gridview1.DataSource would cause a crashing error in case the DataSource is actually a DataSet or even some kind of collection.

Supporting Documentation: [MSDN Documentation on "as"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt(VS.71).aspx)

Comment: Although this didn't generate any errors, when I hover to check the value of my datatable it shows it as null even though my gridview shows populated data.
DataTable dt = gvJobSearchEngine.DataSource as DataTable;

Answer (score 8):

Ambu,

I was having the same issue as you, and this is the code I used to figure it out.  Although, I don't use the footer row section for my purposes, I did include it in this code.

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    // add the columns to the datatable            
    if (GridView1.HeaderRow != null)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text);
        }
    }

    //  add each of the data rows to the table
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        DataRow dr;
        dr = dt.NewRow();

        for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            dr[i] = row.Cells[i].Text.Replace("&nbsp;","");
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    //  add the footer row to the table
    if (GridView1.FooterRow != null)
    {
        DataRow dr;
        dr = dt.NewRow();

        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.FooterRow.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            dr[i] = GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[i].Text.Replace("&nbsp;","");
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do `gridview.bind()` at:

```
if(!IsPostBack)

{

//your gridview bind code here...

}
```

Then you can use `DataTable dt = Gridview1.DataSource as DataTable;` in function to retrieve datatable.

But I bind the datatable to gridview when i click button, and recording to Microsoft document:

> HTTP is a stateless protocol. This means that a Web server treats each
>   HTTP request for a page as an independent request. The server retains
>   no knowledge of variable values that were used during previous
>   requests.

If you have same condition, then i will recommend you to use `Session` to persist the value.

```
Session["oldData"]=Gridview1.DataSource;
```

After that you can recall the value when the page postback again.

```
DataTable dt=(DataTable)Session["oldData"];
```

References:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_0

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/225740/introduction-of-session-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: @John Waclawski   I have the same problem like yours. I found this solution, hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have used below line of code and it works, Try this

```
DataTable dt =  dataSource.Tables[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

This comes in late but was quite helpful. I am Just posting for future reference

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
Data.DataView dv = default(Data.DataView);
dv = (Data.DataView)ds.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
dt = dv.ToTable();
```

Comment: Data.DataView did not have any intellisense popup when I tried your code.