# How to get data from a gridview at runtime on web form asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview on an aspx page.

the gridview already has a datasource and is populated.

i am trying to get the data out of it like this when the user clicks a button:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)grdList.DataSource;
```

however it is showing this result as null!

i understand this to be an issue with postback/viewstate.

can someone please recommend to me a solution by which i can get data out of the gridview?>

Comment: Is the user clicking a button in the grid or on a form that the grid is part of?

Comment: @gsirianni user is clicking on a button that is on the form, not the grid

Comment: Is it a sqlDataSource or objectDataSource that binds to the data grid? If the table is quite large I may rerun the query through an object data source. If not, then saving the data table to the view state will suffice.

Comment: This can be asked before.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785799/how-can-i-export-a-gridview-datasource-to-a-datatable-or-dataset

Comment: @HanletEscaño por el alcohol!~!!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you cannot get the data from asp.net gridview. Instead use this code.

```
Datatable dt = SomeMethodReturningDataTable();

Viewstate["Table"] = dt;

GridView.DataSource = ViewState["Table"];
Gridview.DataBind();
```

If you want to make chnages, pull out the table from viewstate and make changes and then push it again and bind it to grid.

Comment: Why negative ? Any specific reason.

Comment: when i try to do this:Viewstate["Table"] = (DataTable)grdList.DataSource; i am getting 'viewstate' does not exist in current context

Comment: This would work but page size will grow depending on table size. I wouldnt go with this approach unless sure there are always only few records returned.

Comment: You never get Datatable from the datasource. As the asp.net datasource is volatile in nature. See my suggestion.... in my answer.

Comment: @DavidePiras : You can have alternatives, 1. Sql Paging or 2.Compress the viewstate

Comment: @See-Sharp how do you compress viewstate?