# How to get an underlying DataTable from a control (i.e. under DataGridView)?

Tags: c#, winforms, datasource

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = myDataSet1;
dataGridView1.DataMember = "SomeTable";
```

And now I want to get the refference to DataTable back from my dataGridView1.
Something like this:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource... ;
```

I'm aware of BindingContext, but couldn't find the way to get DataTable refference back.

---

Got it.

```
DataSet dataSet = (DataSet)dataGridView1.DataSource;
string tableName = dataGridView1.DataMember;
DataTable dt =dataSet.Tables[tableName];
```

Comment: setting dataSET as datasource and trying to get dataTABLE....

Comment: I also provide a DataMember to point to a particular table in the DataSet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are assigning Dataset as datasource to your gridview. So, the line below would help u.

```
DataTable dt = ((DataSet)dataGridView1.DataSource).Tables[index];
```

Assuming that you have only one datatable in your dataset. you can also use your table name instead of index.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it in this way

```
BindingSource bs = (BindingSource )dgrid.DataSource;
DataTable tCxC = (DataTable ) bs.DataSource
```

Look at this question [How can I export a GridView.DataSource to a datatable or dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785799/how-can-i-export-a-gridview-datasource-to-a-datatable-or-dataset)

Answer (score 0):

You can either be resilient (to avoid null error) or take a chance.

The short version is:

```
DataTable dt = ((DataSet) dataGridView1.DataSource).Tables[0];
```

A more resilient approach (not assuming the view is bound to a DataSet):

```
DataSet ds = dataGridView1 as DataSet;  
if (ds != null)  DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
```

Obviously you can inspect/check the number of tables in the DataSet.