# Copy data from one gridview to another slightly different one

Tags: c#, gridview, copy

I have a gridview1 with 2 columns A and B, and I want to be able to copy those columns into gridview2, which has 3 columns A B and C, where A and B have the same headings as A and B in gridview1.  How do I do this in C#?

Comment: for loop?  Is this a trick question?

Comment: what is gridview1 datasource?

Answer (score 0):

If you are dynamically binding gridview1 with the datatable, then you can add the column C to the datatable and bind it to gridview2.

If you dont have the datatable then you can try converting the gridview1 data to datatable and add the coulmn C and then bind to gridview2.

as in post: [How can I export a GridView.DataSource to a datatable or dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785799/how-can-i-export-a-gridview-datasource-to-a-datatable-or-dataset)