# How to add button click to show next item from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my code, but its not working

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 1;
        if (GridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
            TextBox2.Text = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text;
            TextBox3.Text = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[31].Text;
            TextBox4.Text = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Text;
            i++; 
        }
    }
```

it didn't how next item.

Comment: you need to use ViewState to hold value `i`

Comment: i is in the wrong scope. Create it as a class variable.

Comment: could u pls explain it

Comment: HTTP protocol is state less protocol. So when ever clicked the button every time `i` value will be initialized to 1. So, `i++` as no effect in that scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            int i = ViewState["cnt"]!=null? (int) ViewState["cnt"]:1;
            i = i + 1;
            TextBox1.Text = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
            TextBox2.Text = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text;
            TextBox3.Text = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[31].Text;
            TextBox4.Text = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Text;
            ViewState["cnt"] = i;
}
```

Comment: Sir, in this pgm how can I stop when it reaches the last ite(the last row or nth row). now in the pgm wen I click nxt it will goes to next item and so on, but after the last item it shows error.

Comment: Please check the number of records in the database with help of count property and if i and count is similar , stop the incremention in the I variable

Comment: DataSet ds = (DataSet)GridView1.DataSource;
        int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
     
        int i = ViewState["cnt"] !=null ? (int)ViewState["cnt"] : 1;
        if (count < i)
        {
            i = i + 1;
            TextBox1.Text = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
            TextBox2.Text = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text;
            TextBox3.Text = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[31].Text;
            TextBox4.Text = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Text;
            ViewState["cnt"] = i;
        }
        else
            return;

    }

Comment: change it   if (count != i) instead of  if (count < i)

Comment: sir the pgm shows error in    int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;        and also if ( count!=i)

Comment: int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
error shows here as

NullrefrenceException was unhandled by user code
object refrence not set to an instance of an object

Comment: instead of DataSet ds = (DataSet)GridView1.DataSource use this code :BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)GridView1.DataSource;
DataSet ds = (DataSet) bs.DataSource;

Comment: look this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785799/how-can-i-export-a-gridview-datasource-to-a-datatable-or-dataset